# PDFSharp with xml template in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp in my c# project. In my previous work place I used a PDF component from aspose and in that component ASPOSE provided a xml template feature, where I simply defined the pdf document template in xml format and saved it to hard drive and then from c# code i was opening that template pumping my data and as a outcome it was writing a pdf.

It was quiet fast and I was able to achieve performance.

Can I achive the same using PDFSharp or any other free opensource component.

I mean i want to define my pdf document in xml format and use from any open good opensource components like pdfshpar or Itext etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFsharp/MigraDoc does not support XML templates.

You can create documents from code (any .NET language) and pump in your data where you need it.

That may be a little bit more work than normal report generators, but it gives you much more flexibility than any template-based solution.

Comment: They claim to support XML, but I didn't try it. Check it here - http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=50&Itemid=1

Comment: @Żubrówka: You can import data from XML or any other data source - but you cannot use XML to create templates.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you're still working on this but here is what I have tried.

MigraDoc can import and interpret the MDDDL format. Using this it's easy to write a "text" file that contains all the static text of the template. When it gets to dynamic stuff, all depends on what you are adding :

- For text, just add markers like when writing, say, ASP.Net `<%MyMarker%>`
- For images, you can try putting a marker like `<%ImageURL%>` in the url of the image or in the comments
- For tables, this gets complicated, either :

  - you can put a blank table with a marker `<%dataTable%>` in the comments
  - you can create the table with the columns and the first row (if it has headers) and put a marker in the comments
  - you can create 2 tables, one for the 'empty data' and one like previous with columns and first row. In this case the marker would be something like `<%MyTable{0}%>` in the comments for the empty table and `<%MyTable{1}%>` in the comments in the case of data in the source.

Once MigraDoc has loaded the "template" it's easy to scan recursively the elements and replace the markers.
It might not be the fastest method for creating documents but it saves me from recompiling the entire application each time the client wants to add a space in a report.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me with an example?

Comment: Not easy to provide an example. I'll what I can do and provide a link.

Comment: I'm working on a complete module but here's a template example : https://github.com/TNTPOP/MigraDoc_Templating/blob/master/Templates/DocumentModel.mdddl

Comment: Many thanks for this example. I'm looking forward for complete module.

Comment: I updated a readme document explaining the DocumentModel. It's still incomplete according to what I really want but gives a good look at what it can do.